# How to prevent programmatically added controls to wpf form dissapearing after closing the windows or rebuild the program?

Tags: c#, wpf

This code is used to generate radio button inside a window for each time the the "Add_list" button is clicked. The problem is whenever I close the windows or rebuild the program, every radio button that has been added by clicking the "Add_list" button disappear.

```
 private void Add_list(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
        // add radio button to the list
        string filename = File_name.Text;

        sp_list.Children.Add(new RadioButton
        {

            Margin = new Thickness(8, 0, 0, 0),
            Content = filename

        });

        string [] array = { l_field.Text,width.Text,weight.Text, Concrete_tempreature.Text };
        myAL.Add(array);
        foreach (object obj in myAL)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: You might want to read about [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)...

Comment: Use MVVM and keep the same view model for the different instances of the window.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is - why do you expect it work this way?

Nowhere in your code do you attempt to store the state of your window. WPF doesn't store window states - you need to implement this yourself.